# C# WPF - variable value won't display on Textboxes (DataContext?)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I got a really tricky and annoying problem with my C# WPF Application. I guess it's not a big deal for a good programmer to solve it, but I don't know how to fix it yet. For school, I have to program an application which depicts a process. So I get Data by an XML-File, have to calculate some values, display them for User Interaction etc. and at the end the output is again a file, which can be processed further.

For that, I got different UserControls, which depicts different modules for example, one for the Data Import, the other one for calculating and displayng values and so on. The Main Window is like the free space or the place-maker on which the different modules are loaded depending on where we are in the process.

My problem now is that the values I calculate in my UserControl won't display in my UI respectively my application and I don't really know why. 0 is the only value which is transferred to the application. Curious about it, is that in the Debugger the values are correct, but in the display itself there is only a 0.

Ok, so I show you now the code of the different files (I'm not the best programmer, so maybe the code is sometimes a bit dirty).

I got a Main UserControl, let's call it UC_Main, and in this UserControl you can switch between 3 different other UserControls depending on which Radiobutton in the UC_Main is checked. (The UC_Main is always displayed, because in this there are only the 3 radio buttons and underneath is a big free space, where the different UserControls 1, 2 and 3 are loaded).

**UC_Main.xaml**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="UC1_Template" DataType="{x:Type local:UC1}">
        <local:UC1 DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="UC2_Template" DataType="{x:Type local:UC2}">
        <local:UC2 DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="UC3_Template" DataType="{x:Type local:UC3}">
        <local:UC3 DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border Padding="10">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- In the First Row there are the radio buttons in the second the 
        different UserControls 1, 2 or 3 -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <materialDesign:ColorZone  Mode="PrimaryMid" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <RadioButton x:Name="UC1_radiobutton" Checked="UC1_radiobutton_Checked"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}"
                            Margin="4"
                            IsChecked="True"
                            Content="UserControl1" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="UC2_radiobutton" Checked="UC2_radiobutton_Checked"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}"
                            Margin="4"
                            IsChecked="False"
                            Content="UserControl2" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="UC3_radiobutton" Checked="UC3_radiobutton_Checked"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}"
                            Margin="4"
                            IsChecked="False"
                            Content="UserControl3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>


            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding}" />

        </Grid>
</Border>
</UserControl>
```

**UC_Main.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class UC_Main : UserControl
{

    public UC_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UC1_radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new UC1();
    }

    private void UC2_radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new UC2();
    }

    private void UC3_radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new UC3();            
    }  
}
}
```

To keep it simple, I'll only show you the Code of UserControl 1, because UC 2 and 3 are pretty the same beside other variables or values.

**UC1.xaml**

```
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>

        <!-- To keep the example simple, I got 1 Row and 2 Colums; in each 
             is one TextBox -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />                    
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Grid.Column="0" IsTabStop="False" 
            Text="{Binding Path=variable1, Mode=TwoWay}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            TextAlignment="Center"                             
            Height="25"
            Width="85"
            Foreground="DarkGray"
            IsReadOnly="True" />

            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="False" 
            Text="{Binding Path=variable2, Mode=TwoWay}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            TextAlignment="Center"                             
            Height="25"
            Width="85"
            Foreground="DarkGray"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
</UserControl>
```

**UC_1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class UC1 : UserControl

{

    public MainWindow Speaker;
    public ValueStore vs;

    public UC1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Speaker = MainWindow.AppWindow;
        vs = new ValueStore();
        DataContext = vs;
    }

    public void calc_data()
    {
        // I get the data from the data import (XML-File), which is saved in 
        // a dictionary (strings), converting them to int (so I can do some 
        // math operations) and save them in my variable.
        // UC_Other is a UserControl, where the data import happens
        // dict_other is the dictionary, where the data from the import is 
        // saved

        vs.variable1 = 
 Convert.ToInt32(MainWindow.AppWindow.UC_other.dict_other["0"].Amount);

        vs.variable2 = 
 Convert.ToInt32(MainWindow.AppWindow.UC_other.dict_other["1"].Amount);
    }
```

I call the function calc_data() in an UserControl before, so the data gets calculated and saved in my variables before my UserControl shows up. I declare a new public instance of my UC1 and call the function via UC1.calc_data(); (which is linked to a Button, that is loading my UC_Main).

**ValueStore.cs**

```
    public class ValueStore : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private int _variable1;
    public int variable1
    {
        get { return _variable1; }
        set { _variable1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("variable1"); }
    }

    private int _variable2;
    public int variable2
    {
        get { return _variable2; }
        set { _variable2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("variable2"); }
    }
```

When I look in the debugger after the method calc_data() is called, the values are correct saved in my ValueStore instance and the TextBoxes are showing me in the Debugger that the correct value is in there (the Debugger says "Name: TextBox1" and "Value: {System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: 100}"; 100 is the value I got from the dictionary), but in my application itself there is only the value 0 displayed.

What I don't really understand is, when I change the type from variable1 to string in my ValueStore.cs and save it in my variable in the method calc_data()(without Convert.ToInt32), it doesn't even show a 0 any more in my application, but in the debugger there is still the value "100".

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things here, but my best guess why your debugging-values are correct while none are updated to the GUI is here:

```
public partial class UC_Main : UserControl
{

    public UC_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UC1_radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new UC1();
    }

    private void UC2_radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new UC2();
    }

    private void UC3_radiobutton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new UC3();            
    }  
}
```

You are creating new instances of these classes of the code-behind to the usercontrols. But the usercontrol objects are already created by the `UC_Main.xaml` so during runtime, you have two objects for example of the UC1 class, one which is your bound to your GUI and one where you store and update your values. The one you see on your GUI doesn't get any values updates, which is why you aren't seeing anything.

I currently can't test the code myself, but from what I can see that is where the issue lies. 
Furthermore it is a bit confusing to me, why you are using databinding for code-behind. 
(You are using the code-behind of the UC-classes as datacontext for the main class, which is....weird ;) I think in your case no databinding whatsoever is really needed, however if you want to do stuff with databinding you should probably read up on MVVM)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But the problem now: How can I fix it? I thought, you need Data Binding, so the data gets to the Text Property. How can I solve it the other way? Or what do I have to change, to get the correc value displayed in my TextBoxes?

Comment: In general there are two ways to get the data to your GUI: 1. directly via the code behind (those are the .xaml.cs files created automatically). For example, if you have a textbox in `UC1.xaml`, give it a name: `name="mytextbox"`and then in the code behind you can simply call it like this: `mytextbox.text = "hello world!"`, that's it.

Comment: 2. use databinding: normally this is used for applications of a certain size in conjunction with [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–viewmodel). The reason to use MVVM is to completely decouple the logic and data of the application from the GUI, so that a GUI designer wouldn't need to be an expert on the logic and vice versa.This is also were the whole INotifyPropertyChanged Interface stuff comes in. I would recommend this for bigger apps with more views, for simpler software it is probably easier to go with way nr. 1

Comment: Well I thought the XAMl Files are for GUI Designers and the XAML.cs is for the logic. :D I heard of the MVVM Pattern but I didn't thinkt it would be necessary for my project. Nevermind, I tried it with `TextBox1 = Convert.ToString(vs.variable1)` but now there is no value in my Textbox. Jesus christ what is this. I can provide you my project if you want, so you can take a look at yourself. This whole thing is really frustrating.

Comment: Beside that I really appreciate your time and your help. Very kind from you. :)

Comment: Try `Textbox1.Text`. Think of the `Textbox` just like a class, `Text` then is the property that will change its visible content.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `TextBox1.Text = myvariable`. That didn't work too.

Comment: hmm, ok - can you send a link to the project so I can try to debug it? Probably will take till tomorrow, but I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Wow, thats very kind of you man. I prepare the project now so you can understand it (I'm german, so is the code... :D) and upload it to a public github repository. May take some minutes, but I will write the link here in another comment. Big thanks to you! :)

Comment: Da hätte ich mir ja mein schlechtes Englisch ersparen können :D. Ich lade es schnell in GitHub hoch und melde mich mit dem Link wieder.

Comment: https://github.com/DrKissko/Frustration das ist der Link. Ich hoffe du kannst drauf zugreifen. Wahrscheinlich muss ich dir aber noch die Logik hinter der Applikation erklären.

Comment: kannst mich auch in Skype adden, mein name ist dort `rabbid...` sonst arten eventuelle Erklärungen hier noch aus <.<

Comment: Ok, habs mir durchgeschaut und [hier](https://app.box.com/s/yvcr065doe5ciks0x0oanilgndwwre7d) kannst du das Projekt mit meinen Änderungen runterladen. Die Lösung ist nicht unbedingt die schönste, funktioniert bei mir aber und ich denke es hilft soweit mal um alleine weiter zu kommen. Grundsätzlich ist ein ziemlicher Mix aus Code-Behind und Verwendung von VieModels drinnen, also da würd ich mich noch ein bisschen reinlesen. 
Ich hab ein bisschen kommentiert, falls aber noch was unklar ist einfach fragen. So ich geh jetzt schlafen ;)

Comment: Okay, hab mir diene Verbesserungen angeschaut und soweit auch verstanden. Die Text-Zuweisung für das Text-Property klappt bei deinem Beispiel auch. Wo es aber immer noch hängt bzw. nicht klappt, ist, wenn ich die Text-Property einer Variable von mir in dem UserControl zuweise, kommt wieder nichts an. :( Ich hab die Berechnungsfunktionen unter dem Konstruktor mit einem Button verknüpft, der vor dem Aufruf des UC_Main gedrückt wird. Aber aus irgendwelchen Gründen will es den Wert nicht reinschreiben. Der Button bzw. das Event ist in dem uc_primärplanung.xaml.cs zu finden. Aber vielen Dank bisher

Comment: Hallo, sorry  bin die Woche im Ausland, vlt komm ich nochmal dazu

Comment: Okay alles klar, konnte das Problem mit deiner Hilfe jetzt lösen. Dir vielen Dank! :)